# Enzyme - how to detect if a component is rendered using the shallow() method?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a component called `Foo` and the `render` function is such:

```
render() {
    if (!this.props.something) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Bar />
            <Baz />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I want to test the `Foo` component to see if the `div` is rendered:

```
test('is div rendered', () => {
    const component = shallow(
        <Foo something={false} />
    );

    expect(component.find('div').at(0).exists()).toBeFalsy();
});
```

but the test results in `true`. How can I test, using the `shallow` render method whether `div` exists or not?

Comment: Hey, did my answer fix your problem? @JoeTidee

Comment: I have yet to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use .find().at() it will return an object everytime. The expect assertion should be like this:

```
expect(component.find('div').node).toBe(undefined);
```

Comment: nice! or `expect(component.find('div').length).toBe(0);`